# Remove logout page

Tags: magento-1.9, logout

Is it possible to bypass the logout page in Magento. I don't want to show the logout success page, want to show the current page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using below code

override **app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php**

There is a logoutAction

```
public function logoutAction()
    {
        $this->_getSession()->logout()
            ->renewSession();

        $this->_redirect('*/*/logoutSuccess');
    }
```

changed to

```
public function logoutAction()
    {
        $this->_getSession()->logout()
            ->renewSession();

        $this->_redirectReferer(); //it will redirect to your previous page
    }
```

Comment: Finally got what I want. Thanks, Prashant.

Comment: Never rewrite core files directly as your changes will be overriden during upgrades or can cause problems when patching. Copy the file in `app/code/local` instead and make your changes there instead.

Comment: You need to override class because its not working in app/code/local

Comment: will try to do like that. thanks, Raphael and Prashant..........

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's not a convenient event hook to manipulate the logout redirect location.

`Mage_Customer_AccountController::logoutAction()` sets a redirect to `::logoutSuccessAction()` on the response object *after* the `customer_logout` event is dispatched, and it's the rendering of the *customer/logout.phtml* template which uses PHP to <s>set</s> echo a javascript param to redirect to the homepage with no OOB possibility to pass an arg for an alternate JS-based redirect.

I think the cleanest solution would be to observe `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_logout`, grab the controller object, and overwrite the location header using the response object's `setRedirectWithCookieCheck()` method:

```
public function logoutRedirect($obs)
{
    $obs->getControllerAction()
        ->setRedirectWithCookieCheck(/* your URL param(s) */);
}
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------- **OR**   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

I know it's not elegant, but the easiest method I have found is to copy and modify the template file at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/logout.phtml` to your own theme directory.

Specifically this line:

```
<p><?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->__('You have logged out and will be redirected to our homepage in 5 seconds.') ?></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    setTimeout(function(){ location.href = '<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>'},5000);
//]]>
</script>
```

By modifying location.href url and even the timeout you can point the user to anywhere just after logout. E.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    setTimeout(function(){ location.href = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/login') ?>'},500);
//]]>
</script>
```

Again, it's not elegant, but it should be a quick enough redirect that the quick hop on the page will then shove them to another url, in the above example, back to the login screen.

More details check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955101/magento-redirect-after-logout).